# Netezza JDBC MetaData information for DISTRIBUTE clause

Tags: java, jdbc, metadata, netezza

Is there a way to retrieve the DISTRIBUTE clause from a Netezza table using JDBC MetaData?

Answer (score 2):

After some searching, I found a temporary work around based on the link below:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/ntz/v7r0m3/topic/com.ibm.nz.adm.doc/r_sysadm_user_views.html

The code below does the job, however not through DatabaseMetaData

```
String SQLString  = "SELECT ATTNAME FROM _V_TABLE_DIST_MAP\n";
       SQLString += "WHERE TABLENAME = '" + table + "'\n";
       SQLString += "ORDER BY DISTSEQNO";
       Statement statement = connection.createStatement(); 
       ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(SQLString);
       while( rs.next() ) {
           System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
       }
       rs.close();
```